# Does weather or time of day affect combat in XCOM:EU?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Does weather affect the combat at all in XCOM: Enemy Unknown? For example, does heavy rain reduce visibility, movement or aiming?

Does it make any difference if the mission is at day or at night?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you aim at a target, you can click "More info" to get a detailed breakdown of what modifiers affect your chance to hit the target. There is never a night/day/weather modifier to be seen.

Checking movement and visibility for hidden modifiers is more tricky, but I've not seen any evidence of that either, so I'd say no, there are no such modifiers.

Comment: That's too bad. One of the best (read: most soul-crushingly hard) parts of the original UFO: Enemy Unknown was being forced into a nighttime terror mission and seeing a Chrysalid standing outside the Skyranger. You knew, at that moment, that many of your troops weren't coming home from this one.

Answer (score 4):

No the time of day and weather does not affect line of sight or gameplay in any way. It is just atmospheric visual. This was stated by the game designer Mr Solomon in a video interview.

Comment: Any chance of a link to the interview?